# Isomorphism of Left Kan extensions

Tags: category-theory, kan-extensions

I just got introduced to Kan Extensions in my Introduction to Category Theory course and I am trying to solve this exercise$:$
Let $K:\mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ be a functor. Let $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $F=\mathcal{A}(A,-):\mathcal{A} \rightarrow Set$. Show that $Lan_K \mathcal{A}(A,-)$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{C}(KA,-)$ with unit $\mathcal{A}(A,-) \Rightarrow \mathcal{C}(KA,K-)$ corresponding via Yoned to $id_{KA}$.
I was trying to build a map: $Nat(\mathcal{A}(-,A),LK) \rightarrow \mathcal{C}(KA,K_)$ sending a morphism $\alpha$ to $\alpha _B(f)$, like in the proof of Yoneda lemma , and I think it should work but I don't know how to proceed.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For any functor $G\colon \mathcal B \to \mathrm{Set}$ you have natural bijections
$$
\mathrm{Nat}(\mathcal A(A,-), G\circ K) \cong G(KA) \cong \mathrm{Nat}(\mathcal B(KA,-), G)
$$
which shows that $\mathcal B(KA,-)$ satisfies the universal property of the left Kan extension.

Can you reconstruct the unit from this?

Comment: Is it just that Nat$(\mathcal{A}(A,-),\mathcal{C}(KA,K-)$ is isomorphic from Yoneda to $\mathcal{C}(KA,KA)=id_{KA}$?

Comment: Yes, more or less it boils down to this property.

Comment: And which would be a formal way of reconstructing the unit?

Comment: "Is it just that": yes, and one side has a distinguished element, $1_{KA}$, which must correspond to the unit you want. Formally, such a unit is the initial object of the category of elements of a certain functor.